# Mac App Store: Don't show updates for an uninstalled app

Tags: applications, mac-appstore, macos

I downloaded the free trial ('lite') version of an app on the Mac App Store. I didn't like the app, so I uninstalled it from my computer.

However, the App Store wants me to install updates for this app that I no longer even have.

**Is it possible to tell the Mac App Store that I don't want to be notified about updates for a particular app?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nathan - I made a mistake on a mac where I wasn't the main administrator.   I sure meant to delete the app and even dragged it into the trash, but a day later when the update bubble was still there, I found I didn't really delete the app (In my case it was installed on a different user on a multi user system and rather than move to the trash, it copied itself to the trash). Once I really moved the app to the trash with an admin user and rebooted, the update badge disappeared.

Comment: Hey, great point. I had it not on another user's account but on another partition, and removing that fixed the problem Thanks!